# Featured Image not showing on wordpress hosted under Amazon AWS

Tags: post-thumbnails, amazon

I created a wordpress website on Amazon AWS. I also installed the same theme on wordpress hosted under Bluehost. The problem with wordpress hosted under amazon is that it doesn't show the featured images. the test website for the amazon server is at another.datingat.ph ~ I have managed to make the s3 bucket public, but it still won't show the featured images. Whatever theme I use that supports featured image, the featured image won't show. Plugins work, but I cannot control whether or not I want them to show in a post.

My theme already has "add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); // "

other codes that are connected to featured images are:

> // get the featured image for the post
>       if( has_post_thumbnail($postid) ) {
>           $thumbid = get_post_thumbnail_id($postid);
>       }

and

> // get the featured image for the post
>           if( has_post_thumbnail($postid) )
>           {
>               $thumbid = get_post_thumbnail_id($postid);
>           }

I also tried "sudo yum install php53-gd" but no changes. Also, I think the apache is already set to "AllowOverride All" unless I should check another file via terminal? Please let me know the command that I need to input.

I am still new to this and tried to Google it, but I cannot find an exact answer for my problem. =(

Comment: Does a regular image upload/insert media work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a theme error. As per Oblaksoft,

> it assumes that all images reside on the server's file system and
>   doesn't work with images in the cloud.

It's hard when a theme is not fully compatible with Wordpress hosted under Amazon EC2. =(